# How to do mutation on array in Relay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, relayjs

I want to use mutation in Relay to change an array (not connection). The array is typed GraphQLList in the GraphQL side. The graphql side worked perfectly, but relay side needs **dataID** for each item in an array. And when I am inserting new item or modifying existing item in the array, there are no **dataID** provided? What is the right way to do this? By the way, I am using redux to maintain the list, and submit changes via relay at the end.

The schema:

```js
let widgetType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'Widget',
  fields: () => ({
    label: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    type: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    list: {
      type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString)
    },
    description: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    required: {
      type: GraphQLBoolean
    }
  })
});

let modifyFormMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: 'ModifyForm',
  inputFields: {
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    },
    name: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    },
    userId: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    },
    widgets: {
      type: new GraphQLList(widgetType)
    }
  },
  outputFields: {
    formEdge: {
      type: formConnection.edgeType,
      resolve: (obj) => {
        return {
          node: {
            id: obj.id,
            name: obj.name,
            userId: obj.userId,
            widgets: obj.widgets
          },
          cursor: obj.id
        };
      }
    },
    app: {
      type: appType,
      resolve: () => app
    }
  },
  mutateAndGetPayload: ({
    id, name, userId, widgets
  }) => {
    db.collection('forms').findOneAndUpdate({
      _id: new ObjectID(id)
    }, {
      name, userId, widgets, createAt: Date.now()
    });
    return {
      id, name, userId, widgets
    };
  }
})
```

Relay mutation:

```js
export default class ModifyFormMutation extends Mutation {
  getMutation () {
    return Relay.QL`mutation{modifyForm}`;
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on ModifyFormPayload {
        formEdge
        app { forms }
      }
    `;
  }

  getCollisionKey() {
    return `check_${this.props.app.id}`;
  }

  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
      fieldIDs: {
        formEdge: {node: this.props.node},
        app: this.props.app.id
      }
    }];
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {
      name: this.props.node.name,
      id: this.props.node.id,
      userId: this.props.node.userId,
      widgets: this.props.node.widgets
    };
  }

  getOptimisticResponse() {
    return {
      formEdge: {
        name: this.props.node.name,
        id: this.props.node.id,
        userId: this.props.node.userId,
        widgets: this.props.node.widgets
      }
    };
  }
}
```

And error message from browser:

> "Variable "$input_0" got invalid value
>   {"name":"asdfasdfsa","id":"57e790cec252f32aa805e38d","userId":"57e10a02da7e1116c0906e40","widgets":[{"**dataID**":"client:618507132","label":"sdfas","type":"text","list":[],"description":"","required":true},{"label":"sfasdfasaaa","list":[],"type":"number","description":"","required":"false"}],"clientMutationId":"0"}.↵In
>   field "widgets": In element #0: In field "**dataID**": Unknown field."